# File size difference ClosedXML SaveAs and Orginial file

Tags: c#, closedxml

## Problem:

I use ClosedXML to load an XLSX file and store an copy under different filename. The Filesize is different between both org. File (586KB) and Copy (648KB). 
I open the copy with Excel 2010 and start to scroll in an Worksheet, then crash.
I tried OpenXML and the file size keeps same between org. and copy file (586KB). Excel doesn't crash.

## Questions:

1. Is my code the troublemaker?
2. If not does somebody have a idea how to debug?

## ClosedXML:

```
    private static void LoadAndSaveFile(String input, String output)
    {
        var wb = new XLWorkbook(input);
        wb.SaveAs(output);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputfile = @"D:\Temp\org.xlsx";
        string outputfile = @"D:\Temp\Test.xlsx";

        LoadAndSaveFile(inputfile,outputfile);

    }
```

## OpenXML:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputfile = @"D:\Temp\org.xlsx";
        string outputfile = @"D:\Temp\Test.xlsx";

        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(inputfile);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                // Do work here
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(outputfile, stream.ToArray());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `SaveAs` twice to the same file? I expect there's some kind of corruption going on.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. Do you need to/have to use ClosedXML?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I corrected to one SaveAs, but same behaviour.

Comment: open xml has a tool you can use to do comparisons of spreadsheets...even though you aren't using open xml for development...id imagine you might be able to use the tool

Comment: I have downloaded and compared the files and I can see alot of differences, but to analyze in detail I'm not able. Strange thing is, when I validate the COPY, then no error happens, but excel still crash after scrolling in a worksheet. I opened the file in Excel 2010 and made SaveAs, then the problem with Excel Crash is gone.

Comment: What version of ClosedXML do you use?

Comment: Nuget Package v0.94.2 unfortunately i'm not able to share the excel file (confidential data). What I don't understand is, that Microsoft OpenXML Productivity Tool validation tool doesn't find issues, but Excel 2010 crash , after opening and scrolling in worksheet.

Comment: @Shazter replace the confidential data with zeros and post an issue on github.